# How to Create Custom Shortcut for Language Selection in NOTEPAD++

Tags: notepad++

Whenever I open any KSH files, Notepad++ is not identifying that it's a shell file and so shell commands are not highlighted. So I need to select `Shell` from Language Menu bar as shown in the below screenshot.

Can anyone please tell me how to create a shortcut for selecting a file as shell file **OR** tell me how to change Notepad++ settings so that a .ksh file can be considered as .sh extension file.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add **ksh** to "Settings" ➪ "Style Configurator" ➪ "Language:" *bash* ➪ " + User ext. :" **ksh**

[image: Step 1]

[image: Step 2]

Comment: Because it has *sh* and *bsh* as default extension. Correct me if it's not the desired language style.

Comment: @BinkanSalaryman: I don't see how that's relevant. Wouldn't it be more appropriate to use the "Shell" language? That's the one the OP asked for, which has the styles he wants. (And KSH is not Bash.) Unless the question has a bug...

Comment: Don't confuse "language" with "language style". For example, json files are displayed with the javascript language style in my notepad++ and it works fine.